# How to use Button to control another View

Tags: android

My linear layout has two views:

1. Custom View that display dynamic stuff
2. One button

I'd like to use the button to invalidate the custom view so that it can be redrawn by Android. I've implemented the `onClickListener()` inside the Activity where all the views are located. But the `OnClickListener()` doesn't seem to have access to other viewers other than the view which the listener is bound to. How to call invalidate() on a different view from the button's `OnClickListener()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the other view via [`Activity.findViewById(id)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29). You must cast the returned object to the desired type if you have declared your custom view in an XML layout and have assigned it an `android:id`. Otherwise if you instantiate your View by hand (ie by calling its constructor) simply keep a reference to the object in the form of an instance variable

Comment: I declare the button by hand. And now it's instantiated in the onCreate() of the Activity. Does it mean that I have to use a global instance variable within the Activity so that the onClickListener() can access it?

Comment: You got the idea, but the terminology is wrong :) There ain't anything like `a global variable` in OO world, everything belongs to an object.  In this case, your `Activity` object needs to keep a reference to a `View` object

Answer (score 0):

You can set the views you need as attributes of your Activity and you will be able to access them from the listener method. Cheers!